# never publish one field of item

Tags: sitecore-client

I have a requirement where only one field should never be published to web for all the items.
Is there any provision to restrict one particular field to be published?

Comment: hey Summi, what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Hi Vlad, For SEO reasons, we have to set some field value to false in master db but never in web. So the field should have opposite values in two DBs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The checkbox field "**Never Publish**" appear just on templates and not on field level, so you can not used this functionality.

You can use Security restriction to restrict just one field of an item.

You can use **Everyone** role for restriction, because all users are part of this role, and deny Field read and Read

[image]

Comment: Upvoted.. This should be the perfect solution.. You should never restrict publishing a field, if you do then your schema will be different in "master" and "web" and that will be an inappropriate fix/solution, because your web db should be containing final version of any content with no change in schema/template..

Comment: Thank you! :) This should work for me.

Comment: please mark the answer as correct to help others if it works for you